# Bootstrap inline datepicker with django not working

Tags: html, django, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, inline

I'm quite the newbie at this, but I'm trying to get the bootstrap datepicker inline mode, but my divs are not showing anything once rendered. perhaps you might know what is wrong with my code?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>bootstrap datepicker examples</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href={%static "bootstrap-3.3.2-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" %}>
        <link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" href="{%static 'css/datepicker.css' %}"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href={%static "css/main.css"%}>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="main">
            <div class="datepicker"></div>
        </div>


        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>  {# jQuery #}
        <script src="{% static 'bootstrap-3.3.2-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>     {# Bootstrap #}
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/bootstrap-datepicker.js' %}"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $(".datepicker").datepicker();
            });
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

It works if i use an  tag but then it is not in the inline mode.

Comment: I've never used bootstrap datepicker but I saw the doc and I have a one question, why you put it in div tag not input tag? Maybe it'a an issue

Answer (score 0):

put the following code to the first line of your template file.

`{% load staticfiles %}`

and change

```
<div class="datepicker"></div>
```

to

```
<input class="datepicker" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The {%load staticfiles%} line was already there before. Also, by changing the div to an input,  datepicker is taken out of inline mode, which is not what I need.